# Parse saveInBackground not working after converting to swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

I recently updated my parse project to swift 3 today and to my dismay not a single `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, `getDataInBackground`, `findObjectsInBackGround` `etc` worked. -______- Here is an example of a  section that does not work:

```
newCart.saveInBackground { (saved:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if saved {
                print("saved worked")
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after some quick research, I figured out that in a nutshell, Apple wanted to omit anything that was deemed unnecessary from the swift syntax. This means something as petty as `NS` in `NSError` is not ok with the new swift 3. So in my parse save function above or in any other `getData` or `findObjects`, the only thing you need to do to get Xcode to chill out is change `NSError` in `newCart.saveInBackground { (saved:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in` to `Error`. so that the end result would look like:

```
let newCart = PFObject(className: "Cart")
newCart.saveInBackground { (saved:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
        if saved {
            print("saved worked")
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```